# Bing translator in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bing

I made a web application which translates the entered text into another language. I used Microsoft's Bing translator service for this and it works perfectly. But when i tried this in WPF application it gives an exception which is commented below. The exception says:

> > An unhandled exception of type'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll Additional information: Type 'TranslatorWPF.AdmAccessToken' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.

Any help with this!!

**Code**

```
            string clientID = "abc";
            string clientSecret = "........";

            String strTranslatorAccessURI = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
            String strRequestDetails = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientID), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

            System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strTranslatorAccessURI);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRequestDetails);
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (System.IO.Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AdmAccessToken));
            //Get deserialized object from JSON stream 
            AdmAccessToken token = (AdmAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream()); //** this line throws an exception

            string headerValue = "Bearer " + token.access_token;
            string txtToTranslate = text.Text;
            string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtToTranslate) + "&from=en&to=ur";
            System.Net.WebRequest translationWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
            translationWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", headerValue);
            System.Net.WebResponse response = null;
            response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            System.IO.StreamReader translatedStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode);
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ReadToEnd());

            urdu.Text = xTranslation.InnerText;
```

Comment: so you use DataContractJsonSerializer, but as exception says, class you are trying to deserialize (AdmAccessToken) is not marked with DataContract attribute.

Comment: yes!! i have done it. AdmAccessToken class was not public